# How to prove the security of the MT-based multiplication protocol via the simulation paradigm

Tags: provable-security, multiparty-computation, simulation

It is known that Multiplicaiton Triple (MT) can be used for secure online multiplication, which is defined by $\mathsf{Mul}(x, y)=(z_0, z_1)$, where $x\cdot y = z_0 + z_1$

1. $P_0$ sample random $a$, and $P_1$ sample random $b$
2. By running the MT protocol, party $P_i$ gets $(a_i, b_i, c_i)$, where $i\in\{0,1\}$ and $(a_0 + a_1)(b_0 + b_1) = c_0 + c_1$
3. $P_0$ sends $x-a$ to $P_1$ and obtains $y-b$
4. $P_0$ outputs $z_0 = a_0(y-b) + b_0(x-a) + c_0$, and $P_1$ outputs $z_1 = (x-a)(y-b) + a_1(y-b) + b_1(x-a) + c_1$

To prove the security using the simulation paradigm (e.g. [Yehuda Lindell eprint 2016:46](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046)), I need to construct simulators, say $S_0$, and show that the joint distribution of $S_0$'s output and the functionality $\mathsf{Mul}(x, y)$ is indistinguishable from the joint distribuiton of $P_0$'s view and the protocol's output, i.e.
$(S_0(x,z_0), \mathsf{Mul}(x, y)) \approx_c (\mathrm{view}_0(x, y), (z_0, z_1))$

Given $(x, z_0)$, $S_0$ may do the following

1. sample random $a$
2. emulate MT and obtain $(a_0, b_0, c_0)$
3. by the equation $z_0 = a_0(y-b) + b_0(x-a) + c_0$, figure out $t = y-b$
4. output $(x, a; (a_0, b_0, c_0), t)$

Note that in setp 3, to compute $t$, $a_0$ should be invertible. If the underlying algebric structure is $\mathbb Z_q$, where $q$ is not prime, say $q = 2^l$, then $a_0$ can only be set to be odd? When I construct $S_1$ as above, it will get worse. So

1. how the construct simulators for $P_i$ correctly?
2. how to prove the indistinguishability between the joint distributions?